# Can the AVSpeechUtterance audio be recorded?

Tags: avaudiorecorder, siri

I am wondering if the audio from Siri's speech synthesis can be recorded programmatically and then saved locally.

I am wanting to create some custom voice alert audio files in Siri's 'voice' to be used to for spoken Push Notification messages instead of just using a generic sound alert.

eg I would get Siri to say "Attention David, your window has been closed due to rain" in a Push Notification alert by using a previously recorded voice file, even when the home automation App isn't running.